# NET 3.5 - MVC PetShop application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is there really a MVC PetShop application? ScottGu mentioned something, but was he kidding?

Update

Yes, but have they done it in 3.5?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codeplex.com/petshopmvc

Answer (score 1):

I think they're talking about the [MS .Net Pet Shop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479071.aspx) - which was created as a benchmarking application to compare .Net/SQL with J2EE/Oracle - they may well be working on an updated version - I can't seem to find a reference to an MVC Pet Shop on ScottGu's blog.

I know Scott Hanselman has [mentioned it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSamplesOxiteAndCommunity.aspx), but I don't know how serious he was - he was talking about reading code, and not taking everything that comes from Redmond as gospel.

However [Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/) has been working on the [MVC Storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/) - I'm not sure if it's a Pet Store specifically.